# Change Font of JOptionPane showMessageDialog Boxes

Tags: java, html, css, swing, joptionpane

I have been trying to change the font of the boxes within `showMessageDialog`, but I am unsure how to do so. Here's the code I have so far:

```
Object[] choice = {"Previous", "Next"};

value = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
    null, 
    "<html><body><b style='font-family: Sitka Display; font-size: 14px'; <p style='width: 400px;'>" + text, 
    "Header Test", 
    JOptionPane.YES_OPTION, 
    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, 
    null, 
    choice, 
    choice[0]);
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/848NS.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn’t close your `<b>` element.

Comment: Good point @VGR. OP, if HTML/CSS is not working as expected, first try it in a browser, then validate. Personally, I'd get rid of the `<b>` tag completely, and instead do all the styling in the `<p>` (*including* making the text bold).

Answer (score 0):

You only need to create a JLabel to achieve this.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("...");
label.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 14));
```

And pass it to showOptionDialog as a parameter.